# Generating dynamic quiz questions without using eval

Tags: php

I want to create a quiz, where I can pull 20 random questions from a set of say, 80. I want the questions however to be able to have some scripted elements, such as random numbers, generated images and code snippets.

The obvious answer would be to put this code in the database and use eval

```
$query_from_db  = '<div>
<?php

//php to run
function dosomething() {
     //bleh
}

?>
</div>
';

php echo eval($query_from_db);
```

However I know this is wrong and I don't want to do this, please don't tell me not to use eval. What I need is to be able to understand how I can approach this from a different way. Should I put my code in different includes and call it, should I use template engine, should I put it in separate PHP files and call them?

This is so the questions can be made up of dynamic code for random numbers, random graphs, random text, generated on the fly for each person who takes it.

Comment: Is some tutor setting a homework exercise or something? Because I commented on an almost-identical question which appeared yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570009/building-a-quiz-with-complex-question-elements

Comment: Absolutely. And the same answer: **Eval** is an alias of evil.

Comment: "Should I put my code in different includes and call it, should I use template engine, should I put it in seperate php files and call them?"...these are listed as if they are mutually exclusive options, but I'd say that the middle one is a conceptual idea (and a good one, potentially), but the other two are just implementation details, rather than comparable alternative approaches. So to ask which one you should use is not really a good question. But pluggable templates, yes, that's probably a good way forward as a concept.

Comment: `The obvious answer would be to put this code in the database and use eval` er, no. No no and no; that is not the obvious answer, or even an option that should be considered. The normal thing to do, based on the description would be to allow a whitelist of placeholders which you'd be replacing at render time. like `:random-number:` is what's stored in the db OR to be storing js (which to php and the db is just text and therefore inert).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to NOT use an `eval` approach and instead add some parameters for each question which can be substituted out before they are sent to the browser.

You may want to have a look at the `sprintf` function for substituting into strings in a formatted manner.

The format of your parameters (which I'd add into a different field/fields) depends on what you're hoping to achieve with your quiz and the questions in it.